# react-google-maps: trying to create a toggleable infowindow for each marker

Tags: react-google-maps

I know similar questions have been asked on SO before, but I've tried implementing the solutions in the answers and nothing seems to be working.

So, here's the problem I'm having: I'm using react-google-maps to generate a map. The map has multiple markers. Every time I click on a specific marker, I want an infowindow to pop up. The thing is, right now, everythime I click on a marker, the infowindows for all the markers pop up, as shown below:

[image]

Would you care to glance over my code and tell me what the problem is:

```
  render() {


const MapWithAMarker = compose(
  withStateHandlers(() => ({
    isOpen: false,
  }), {
    onToggleOpen: ({ isOpen }) => () => ({
      isOpen: !isOpen,
    })
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props =>
  <GoogleMap
  defaultZoom={7}
  defaultCenter={{ lat: 37.468319, lng: -122.143936 }}
  containerElement={<div style={{ height: `300px`, width: `400px`, position: `absolute` }} />}
  mapElement={<div style={{ height: `300px` }} /> }
  containerElement={
   <div style={{height: 300, width: 600}}></div>
 }
  loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
  googleMapURL={"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCk55BnGfoigxDUwDaiYiyn9tFThcJVsPA"}
  >

   {store.results.data.map( (result, index) => {
                                if(result.status.color=='success'){
                                return <Marker
                                key={ index }
                                position={{ lat: result.contract_location.lat, lng: result.contract_location.lng }}    
                                icon={ '/img/darkgreen_MarkerA.png' } 
                                onClick={() => props.onToggleOpen(index)}                 
                                >
                                   {props.isOpen && <InfoWindow onCloseClick={() => props.onToggleOpen(index)}>
                                   <div>hi</div>
                                   </InfoWindow>}
                                </Marker>
                                }

                                if(result.status.color=='warning'){
                                  return <Marker
                                  key={ index }
                                  position={{ lat: result.contract_location.lat, lng: result.contract_location.lng }}    
                                  icon={ '/img/yellow_MarkerA.png' } 
                                  onClick={() => props.onToggleOpen(index)}                 
                                  >
                                    {props.isOpen && <InfoWindow onCloseClick={() => props.onToggleOpen(index)}>
                                    <div>hi</div>
                                    </InfoWindow>}
                                  </Marker>
                                  }

                                if(result.status.color=='danger'){
                                  return <Marker
                                    key={ index }
                                    position={{ lat: result.contract_location.lat, lng: result.contract_location.lng }}    
                                    icon={ '/img/red_MarkerA.png' }
                                    onClick={() => props.onToggleOpen(index)}                  
                                    >
                                       {props.isOpen && <InfoWindow onCloseClick={() => props.onToggleOpen(index)}>
                                       <div>hi</div>
                                       </InfoWindow>}
                                    </Marker>
                                    }


                                 }
                                )}


  </GoogleMap>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mapped your InfoWindows out and conditionally render them with `props.isOpen`.

The onClick event for InfoWindow accepts an index argument.
However... in your `onClick` function, any click event will toggle isOpen to true (regardless of the index)

Since all InfoWindows depend only on the boolean isOpen, clicking one will set `isOpen` to `true`, and all of them open :)

A way around this is to store the index of the clicked marker. eg: `clickedMarkerIndex = x`.
Then, check `{props.clickedMarkerIndex === index }` and render the InfoWindow only if its' index matches the index of the clicked marker.